# putting input in a database using mysqli

Tags: php, input, mysqli

I'm trying to use mysqli to insert data from a form into a database. However I'm not getting it to work :/

This is my code from the page you get to after you filled in the form. The form is not the problem because the variables $headin $author and $thecontent all have data in them. And in the real code database username password and name have real values :)

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Send!</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

 ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = '**';
$DB_PASS = '***';
$DB_NAME = '***';
@ $db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo 'Error.';
exit();
}

$author = $_POST['author']; 
$heading = $_POST['heading'];
$thecontent = $_POST['thecontent'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO articles ('heading', 'author', 'content')
 VALUES ('$heading','$author','$thecontent')';   

$result = $db->query($query);
    if ($result) {
    echo $db->affected_rows."This was added.";
    } 
    else {
    echo "somethings gone very wrong.";
    }

$db->close();


?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're using mysqli (good!) why aren't you using prepared statements? Your code is subject to SQL injection (say hello to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)).

Comment: thanks I got it to work using prepared statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add single quotes `'` on row names and you have to add double quotes for INSERT:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO articles (`heading`, `author`, `content`)
 VALUES ('$heading','$author','$thecontent')";
```

Also escape your strings:

```
$author = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['author']); 
$heading = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['heading']);
$thecontent = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['thecontent']);
```